# Android compiler issue with resource type of id (exit code 139)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have an android application which compiles and operates fine. I recently want to add an id resource which I can use to dynamically assign an id to a layout which I inflate on the fly. To do so I created a xml file inside /res/values/ called ids.xml (filename doesn't matter as I have tried different names)

The file content is quite simple, along the lines of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <item type="id" name="newLayoutId"/>
   <item type="id" name="otherLayoutId"/>
</resources>
```

As soon as this file is added to my project, it will no longer compile giving the following error

```
android-apt-compiler: Command "/Users/X/Source/Android Eclipse/sdk/platform-tools/aapt package -m -J /Users/X/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea12/compile-server/_temp_/android_apt_output5946629892214876299tmp -M /Users/X/Code/projectName/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/X/Code/projectName/res -I /Users/X/Source/Android Eclipse/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar" execution failed with exit code 139
```

Removing the file causes the application to compile fine again. I can easily work around this by changing the type of the resource from id to string or other valid resource. But I really would like to find out why this error is happening.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When accessing these ids in your other xml files, are you still using the plus sign?(`"@+id/newLayoutId"`) If so, get rid of it.

Comment: No i was not, the only spot where I would be referencing it would be through java code using the R object
aka R.id.newLayoutId
 I am getting the compile error, even if there are no reference to the item at all

Answer (score 1):

Same here, but my exit code is 138.

> android-apt-compiler: Command
>   "/Users/robertwang/Dev/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/build-tools/19.0.0/aapt
>   package -m --auto-add-overlay --extra-packages
>   com.evernote.androidsdk:com.actionbarsherlock:com.origamilabs.library
>   -J /Users/robertwang/Library/Caches/IdeaIC12/compile-server/*temp*/android_apt_output9115494255397050428tmp
>   -M /Users/robertwang/Dropbox/Work/Projects/HomeNeatly-AndroidKickstartr/HomeNeatly/AndroidManifest.xml
>   -S /Users/robertwang/Dropbox/Work/Projects/HomeNeatly-AndroidKickstartr/HomeNeatly/res
>   -S /Users/robertwang/Dropbox/Work/Projects/HomeNeatly-AndroidKickstartr/HomeNeatly/ext-libs/evernote_library/res
>   -S /Users/robertwang/Dropbox/Work/Projects/HomeNeatly-AndroidKickstartr/actionbarsherlock/res
>   -S /Users/robertwang/Dropbox/Code/github/StaggeredGridView/res -I /Users/robertwang/Dev/adt-bundle-mac/sdk/platforms/android-17/android.jar"
>   execution failed with exit code 138

So I look all over my project for the last xml file I create, delete menu.xml then it all compiled fine.

However I try to add the same xml back with different name, it also compiled fine! Really don't what's going on inside!

Answer (score 0):

exit code 139 does not appear to be related to this file; having said that, I have greped the aapt source for  "139" and even "exit code" and can't find it.  I have created the file (res/values/test.xml) in a working project I have sitting around and it compiles okay.

bottom line: I cant find how this error is related to that file

it is worth mentioning that I see references all over the web to this exit code, you are not alone. ...and I see that someone has already +1'd you :-)